# Search in search-as-you-type field with fuzziness

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I'm currently trying to implement search-as-you-type feature. My wish is to allow user to see search results before full query is typed, and even if it is typed with typos.
For example: "titane"->find "Titanic" by prefix with single typo

I'm following [this](https://coralogix.com/blog/elasticsearch-autocomplete-with-search-as-you-type/) arcticle to create efficent search-as-you-type query, and those questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65817192/elasticsearch-fuzziness-with-bool-prefix-type) ,[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63625887/how-to-add-fuzziness-to-search-as-you-type-field-in-elasticsearch)), and it allows me to search while **first word has typos, and user continues to type second query word** but **I need to implement fuzziness in prefix of first word**

I've come up with something like this, but as I mentioned, it's not working properly:

```
"multi_match": {
    "query": query_text,
    "type": "bool_prefix",
    "fields": [
        "title_on_the_fly",
        "title_on_the_fly._2gram",
        "title_on_the_fly._3gram",
        "title_on_the_fly._index_prefix",
    ],
    "fuzziness": "AUTO"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-bool-prefix), bool_prefix does not support fuzzy.

> The fuzziness, prefix_length, max_expansions, fuzzy_rewrite, and
> fuzzy_transpositions parameters are supported for the terms that are
> used to construct term queries, but do not have an effect on the
> prefix query constructed from the final term.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but maybe there is a way to use one of another possible "type" parameters?

Comment: Other types like "best_fields" will work but the best type for search_as_you_type is "bool_prefix"